# Navigation HTML with Scala

Tags: html, scala, treenode, tree-traversal

I want to open a html Source with Scala and then navigate. I new to Scala, so my question is what is the best class to use to navigate. Where I would have methods like getFirstChild?

```
//get html
val html = Source.fromURL("https://www.google.com")
// now what?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML document is an xml document, so you can use scala capabilities to working with xml. [Here](http://bcomposes.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/basic-xml-processing-with-scala/) is an article which gives basic overview of XML processing capabilities of scala. Of course, There are plenty of java/scala libraries which simplify standart scala mechanism.

Comment: It's worth noting that a valid HTML document isn't always a valid XML document (unless it's XHTML) - not to mention that real world HTML pages often aren't even valid HTML to begin with. One solution is to pass the HTML through a cleaner library which will attempt to correct anything that isn't valid XML - [here's an example](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-html-parsing) using a Java library called HTMLCleaner.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Scala doesn't have direct support for HTML ( although it has support for XML in built ). For example:

```
scala> import scala.io.Source
scala> import scala.xml.XML
scala> val html = Source.fromURL("https://www.google.com")
scala> XML.loadString(html.toString)
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
```

This is because all HTML documents are not well formed XML documents. To overcome this, you can use any HTML processing library in Java. Check for an example here:

http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-html-parsing